# How to configure GOOGLE_CUDA?

Tags: tensorflow

In order to run the TensorFlow verbs code without cuda, I closed part of my code with the define of GOOGLE_CUDA. When I'm trying to run the code, I see that the GOOGLE_CUDA is always undefined in my files, even when I build the TensorFlow with cuda, but in other files that use it, it's defined.
What should I do in order to make my code know this define?